# If the desktop under a certain user becomes slow, how to improve performance?

Tags: linux, performance, arch-linux

I am using Arch Linux, and the default username has become slow and unresponsive over time. I created a new user to see it was fast and as good as new. I don't want to delete the default user, as a lot of customizations and settings have gone into the same. How can I get back the old performance in it?

Comment: that's the problem... your customizations and settings. You answered your own question. We have no idea what you did/installed, so how can we fix it?

Comment: Heh, same thing happens on Windows. Create new user profile and add stuff back till it breaks. Create new profile and don't add back the stuff that causes it to break. Empiric evidence gathering solves this one, no easy answers.

Comment: @Logman, By customizations I referred to certain keyboard shortcuts that I assigned for repetitive tasks and commands. Nothing that is heavy and alters the GUI.

Comment: @jadelord There is something running that is causing the problem with that profile. You do not say if the problem is continuous or on logon. You have not given us anything to go on. As Fiasco Labs mentions, you have to rebuild it from scratch or try to disable items one by one until you find the culprit.